# algorithms in Cuda

Tags: c, cuda

I have created a program in C and trying to change it to CUDA.

the program output files with numbers for graph.

with CUDA I can get the program to output the files but the calculations have not been done

here the code with the algorithms

```
__device__ void nextState(int i, darray oldv, darray newv, darray w, int t){

double dv;

   dv = -8*oldv[i]*(oldv[i]-0.1)*(oldv[i]-1) - oldv[i]*w[i];

/* Stimulate in leftmost region */
   if ((t >=10) && (t<=15) && (i < 4))
     dv += 2;

/* diffusion */
  newv[i] = oldv[i] + 0.1 *dv +
            0.1 *1.0*(oldv[i-1]-2*oldv[i]+oldv[i+1])/(1.0*1.0);

  w[i] = w[i] + 0.1 *eps(oldv[i],w[i])
                        *(-w[i]-8*oldv[i]*(oldv[i]-0.1-1));

}

__device__ double eps(double u, double v)
{
    return (0.002 + (0.2*v)/(u+0.3));
}

__global__ void run_state(darray* oldv, darray* newv, darray* w, int* t)
{
int i = threadIdx.x;

nextState(i, *oldv, *newv, *w, *t);

}
```

also `#define N 256;` with `run_state<<< 1, N>>>(d_oldv, d_newv, d_w, d_t);`
so it should output 256 values. it does that but all are at 0.000...

so I am wandering if I have made a mistake in any of these functions.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you doing error checking on all of your cuda calls? (cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy, kernel call, etc.)  It's quite possible that the data is not making it to the GPU correctly or that the GPU is not even running the code you think it is.

Comment: @Robert I was wandering if there was anything wrong with the functions I put up, and then if not I would assume it would be to do with what you said.

Comment: I do not understand why do you need to pass "pointer to pounter" arguments to your kernel ? by this I mean d_oldv, d_newv and d_w. Note that you cannot dereference a host pointer on the device

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check if your function is working properly try using `__host__` directive so the same function can also be used on host then you can test and debug it locally. If it works on the host and doesn't work on the device, you are probably doing something wrong when copying the information from host to device and back.

Declare your function like this:

```
__host__ __device__ void nextState(int i, darray oldv, darray newv, darray w, int t)
```